# Synonymize [yield] and [yield-keyword]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield) and [yield-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield-keyword) should be synonyms.

- There are [11 questions with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield-keyword+yield)
- there are [44 questions with yield-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield-keyword)
- there are [676 questions with yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield)

I don't think you can really be an useful expert on the yield-keyword,
*"Did you know that there are 2 vowels in the yield keyword?"* (Quote: an expert on the [yield-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield-keyword), who is not an expert on the notion on [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yield)).

I don't have the tag rep to propose the synonym.

Possibly they should also be  synonymous with [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generator), or [lazy-evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lazy-evaluation). But that is a issue for another time

Comment: I can think of several other definitions of yield that could have questions.  Particularly for financial software.  Also, yield means a few things even in CS that have nothing to do with lazy evaluation.  It isn't even in the first 3 or 4 that come to mind.

Comment: Yield doesn't always have to do with generators or lazy evaluation, for example Java's [`Thread.yield()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--)

Comment: The tag descriptions do not appear to be synonymous. `yield-keyword` is what you describe. `yield` seems to be different things dependent on the language used. It should probably be retagged and burniated.

Comment: Good Point @Gabe, ,Shadow

Comment: @GabeSechan If someone needs help with yield in the financial sense, then they should really be looking at money.stackexchange.com or quant.stackexchange.com.  It is doubtful that many SO users know enough about finance to be able to answer such a question

Comment: The `yield` keyword is also different in intent between Python and Ruby; for Python it creates a generator, for Ruby it creates a block.  I would really not want to see these synonymized.  I'm with @shadow on this one; retag + burnination seems more appropriate here.

Comment: Completed by the community.